# Learning to read handwriting

Tags: reading, writing, hebrew

What are some ways to learn to read anything handwritten in a new language. There are infinite variations and variables, which makes it different.

I’m looking for general information, but specifically in modern Hebrew.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several options but ultimately it comes down to you practicing writing and reading cursive:

1. It's old-fashioned, but get several pen pals. Write back and forth to them. They will have different handwriting from each other and from you and will thus expose you to variety in handwriting. Also, the writing will help you improve your Hebrew.
2. You need to practice writing. You can do this by making handwritten flashcards, copy stories by hand, and of course writing to your pen pals.
3. Practice reading Hebrew cursive where you can find it. As you can imagine, most learning materials aren't written in cursive. It looks like [LearnHebrewPod](https://www.learnhebrewpod.com/reading.asp?id=2326&type=2) can toggle their materials between Print & Script (top of the lesson), though keep in mind that no one writes with *nikkud*.

Also, [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oS-quxkdSzc) are [two](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nTzyRdoXlbs) Modern Hebrew handwriting videos.